# How to increment copies of a file using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, copy, move

I have to move files from one folder to another every hour.

If there is a copy of a file in the destination folder I want it named FileName_1. In the next hour if the original file is copied again from the source want it named FileName_2. If it still exists then FileName_3, then FileName_4 so on and so forth.

Currently, I can get to FileName_1 only. The issue is that since I change the file name and replace it with a new one it overwrites FileName_1.

Hold up a second. I did my homework here. I have a code block that will sort the files by names, split the name, and add 1 to the file counter but I don't reach this part of the code because the initial check (if the file exists) is always true after the first copy is made.

Any help is appreciated.

Code:

```
#Sources 
$source = "C:\Users\Desktop\TEST\Test_1\*"
$sourceNameChange = "C:\Users\Desktop\TEST\Test_1"

#Destination 
$destination = "C:\Users\Desktop\TEST\Test_2"

Function MoveFiles{
    Param(
        [string]$src,
        [string]$dest,
        [string]$srcNameChange
    )
   Get-ChildItem -Force -Recurse $src -ErrorAction Stop -ErrorVariable SearchError | ForEach-Object{
     
        $fileNameSrc = $_.Name
        $baseNameSrc = $_.BaseName
        # Check for duplicate files
        $testPath = Test-Path -Path $dest\$baseNameSrc.*
        If( $testPath )
        {
        $fileCounter = 1
        $newName = $_.BaseName + "_"+$fileCounter + $_.Extension
        "$srcNameChange\$fileNameSrc" | Rename-Item -NewName $newName
        }  
        $testPathDest = Test-Path -Path $dest\$baseNameSrc_.*
       If($testPathDest){            
           $sort = Get-Item -Path $dest\* -Filter *$baseNameSrc_* | Sort-Object -Property Name -Descending 
           $destFileName = $sort[1].BaseName
           $destFileCounter = $destFileName.Split("_")[1]
           $destNewName = $_.BaseName + "_"+($destFileCounter+1) + $_.Extension
           "$srcNameChange\$fileNameSrc" | Rename-Item -NewName $destNewName
       }
    }
    Move-Item -Path $src  -Destination $dest -Force
} 
MoveFiles -src $source -dest $destination -srcNameChange $sourceNameChange
```

Comment: These are only files or are there folders that need to be moved to?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Just the files

Comment: Could you clarify on the use of `-Recurse` on the first call to `Get-ChildItem` ? Are you moving all files from all subfolders on `$source` to `$destination` without preserving folder structure ?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I was told to move everything from `$source`. I don't usually know what is put into `$source`. It could be folders and/or files. Also being new to Powershell using `Get-ChildItem` seemed more foolproof. Preserving folder structure is not important. At the end of the day what matters is that all the files are moved.

Comment: @Brute - a simpler method would be to add a postfix with a datetime stamp to the file name. no need to find the previous number ... just use a sufficiently granular time unit. minutes is usually enuf ... but you can get it down to milliseconds if needed. [*grin*]

Comment: I agree with Lee_Dailey, my answer was purely to answer the question however removing the need for checking if the files are there would be far more efficient and easier code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added lots of inline comments to help you get through the logic of the function, basically, what your code is missing is a loop that increases the index of the file you're moving until it doesn't exist.

**Note**, be sure that `$destination` is not a folder contained inside `$source` or you would end up with unexpected results due to the use of `-Recurse`.

```
function Move-Files {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string] $Source,
        [parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $Destination
    )
    begin {
        # if destination doesn't exist, create the folder
        if(-not (Test-Path $destination)) {
            $null = New-Item -Path $destination -ItemType Directory
        }
    }
    process {
        # get all the files in `$source` and iterate over them
        Get-ChildItem $source -File -Recurse -Force | ForEach-Object {
            # check if a file with the same name exists in `$destination`
            $thisFile = Join-Path $destination -ChildPath $_.Name
            # if it does exist
            if(Test-Path $thisFile) {
                $i = 0
                # start a loop, using `$i` as index
                do {
                    # increase `$i` on each iteration and get a new name
                    $newName = $_.BaseName + "_" + ++$i + $_.Extension
                    # join the destination path with the new name
                    $thisFile = Join-Path $destination -ChildPath $newName
                    # do this while `$thisFile` exists on `$destination`
                } while(Test-Path $thisFile)
            }
            # if we are here we can assume that either the file didn't exist
            # on `$destination` OR the `do` loop got us a new name
            Move-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Destination $thisFile
        }
    }
}

$source = 'C:\Users\Desktop\TEST\Test_1'
$destination = 'C:\Users\Desktop\TEST\Test_2'
Move-Files -Source $source -Destination $destination
```

Comment: @Brute my pleasure :)